# How do I access a file in a systems jboss bin, from other system

Tags: java, file-io, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I have a file in the jboss bin folder, on a system. I have to access this file from other system. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

-Aj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the file available via a webapp or an ejb